# Query on handling TAB character?

Tags: c, language-agnostic

In `ASCII CharacterSet` world, Below 3 whitespace characters have a number.

```
Space(32) LineFeed(10) CarriageReturn(13)
```

So, It is easy to write a program to read or write such whitespace characters in standard way using some programming language(like C) in a portable way, by using following notations,

```
LineFeed - '\n'
Carriage Return - '\r'
Space - ' '
```

I learnt that `TAB` is collection of sometimes 4 or sometimes 8 `Space` characters.

My question:

How do i understand the meaning of '\t' character in programming language(like C)? When there is no standard definition of TAB in `CharacterSet` world?

Comment: "TAB is collection of sometimes 4 or sometimes 8 Space(32) characters." Maybe in your editor, but in the world of code points it is its own entity: `'\t'`, [ASCII value #9](http://www.asciitable.com).

Comment: In C, we say like 'if(ch==’\t’)', How does it work, when you do not how many space characters  are coming with TAB?

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh you mean value 9 as per ASCII?

Comment: There are no "space" characters coming "with TAB"; it is its own distinct code point. It is rendered differently, depending on the output media, but in the end it is a single code-point.

Comment: You mean a TAB will be stored as value 9(in 8bits) in ASCII world, whether TAB is read as input or writen as output ?

Comment: @overexchange yes. A tab isn't spaces, a tab is a tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASCII, a Horizontal Tab is code 9.  The ASCII Horizontal Tab is code 9 regardless of what character set the code is written in.

In C, `'\t'` is the horizontal tab in the character set of the source code, regardless of the character set of the IO.  the integer value of `'\t'` may/may not be 9.

The character set of the code and character set of IO (e.g. files) are commonly the same.  In 2014, there are often both ASCII (at least for the ASCII codes 0 - 127).

In C, printing a  `'\t'` is somewhat precise;

> Moves the active position to the next horizontal tabulation position
>   on the current line. If the active position is at or past the last defined horizontal
>   tabulation position, the behavior of the display device is unspecified. C11 §5.2.2 2

With ASCII, the [Horizontal Tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_Tab#Tab_characters) is intended not to represent printable information, but rather to control devices.  The ASCII original definition led to ambiguity as to the precise  action of a control device: move to the next tabulation stop.

Given these similar, but different meanings, and acknowledging other languages have various meanings, the precise meaning is highly dependent on the situation.  Therefore to maintain portability, other situation dependent info is needed (e. g. a definition or list of the tab stops) to *precisely* generate and interpret a horizontal tab.

Recommend:
Unless the data format requires ( [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile#Makefiles)), do not generate tabs, but spaces.  Upon reading a `'\t'`, interpret it, as able, the same as 1 or more consecutive spaces.

Comment: I remember some holy wars on usage of tabs vs spaces. Maybe you should clarify what "Recommend" means: is it your personal opinion? Is it a consensus of some specific community?

Comment: @anatolyg The unattributed "Recommend" here is my opinion backed by my reputation.

Comment: @chux there is lot of stuff in your answer, many new points for me, i will read this properly and ask you questions.

Comment: @chux so source code can have its own character set in addition to IO having its own character set? I never thought about it!!! Java & C source code will have their own character sets?

Comment: @chux Can i say like, scenario of, notepad.exe interpreting TAB character in a xyz.txt to display TAB character, IS SAME AS, java.exe interpreting TAB character mentioned in abc.java[System.out.println("\t");] to display TAB character. If yes, then notepad.exe program will interpret TAB character in xyz.txt based on what reference and display TAB? and Java.exe program will interpret TAB character based on what reference and display TAB?

Comment: @overexchange notepad.exe _appears_, by experimentation, to have a constant tab stops every 8 columns.  I do not know if this is specified in notepad.exe documentation.  Using a fixed tab stop of 8 is quite common in my experience.  I would use this as the default unless some other configuration information is available.  (Not familiar enough to comment about java.exe)

Comment: @overexchange: Note that this is the same as other characters. `\r\n` may appear in notepad as a 5 pixel gap between lines but in hyperterminal it's probably a 9 pixel gap. Similarly, `\n` may appear in vim as a 6 pixel gap between lines but in notepad it's a square box (or is that ^M? I don't remember). Don't confuse what the UI displays on screen with the data on disk.

Comment: @slebetman  I am trying to understand this point because i sometimes get this error when i interpret python program. I write the code in Notepad++ and interpret using python tool on shell.`PS C:\Users\MOHET01\git\CS61A_Fall2012\Homework2> python -i .\Higher_order_function_Q2.py
  File ".\Higher_order_function_Q2.py", line 9
    i = 1       # Initial value
                              ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
>>>` carot symbol points to `e` of `value`

Comment: @overexchange: Python interprets a tab as eight spaces. So if your text editor displays them differently you need double check. For this reason, python programmers discourage mixing tabs and spaces in code. I believe the recommendation is to always use spaces? So in an editor like notepad you need to use the spacebar. In vi or emacs or visual studio you can configure the preferences so that your editor inserts spaces (not tab) when you press the tab key.

Comment: @slebetman so my notepad++ editor is intentionally using 4 bytes to  insert value 9(tab) on my file for my display facility for providing the meaning of tab, correct? Despite we would have required only 1 byte to actually store? or may be as you said: `Don't confuse what the UI displays on screen with the data on disk.`

Comment: What I mean is that in most editors 4 space characters and one tab characters look the same but they're not the same on disk. In most programming languages it doesn't matter but in python it does.

Answer (score 0):

What to do with tab depends on

- What kind of input you are processing
- The capability of the device you are targeting

A tab is meant as an elastic delimiter that tells the device to move to next tab stop. Replacing tabs with N spaces is just poor man's handling. To correctly render a tab you need to figure out appropriate tab-stops somehow.

When printing a table that uses tabs as field separator onto a text terminal you need to load the table, count the number of characters in each column, and fill each field with spaces so the fit the widest field in that column. In this case the length of the tab is determined by the number of characters you have to write before next column, which in turn varies with the contents of current row.

A practical example of tab-stops: http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/

Answer (score 0):

This is just an addition to other answers. The tab stops are usually set at positions `4*n` or `8*n` (here I am using 0-based numbering of positions). If a cursor is at position `x`, after outputting a tab character it jumps to next tab stop:

```
x = (x / 8 + 1) * 8;
```

Or if the tab-stops have spacing of `s` (usually `s` is 4 or 8, as mentioned):

```
x = (x / s + 1) * s;
```

However, if tab-stops are completely flexible (e.g. the user can specify each tab-stop in Microsoft Word), no such formula exists.